# Returning T(t) with T=int&, how?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T&& t) {
    return T(t);
}

int main() {
    int x;
    foo(x);
}
```

So, I know T=int& here but I don't understand what happens at return line to make this vaild. Can someone explain how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T(t)` performs [explicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) (functional cast), when `T` is `int&`, as the effect `T(t)` produces a reference binding to `t`, and then returns as the return value (return type is `int&` too).

Comment: Thanks! That's totally understandable. It was hard to see for me since I was expecting it to construct something.

Comment: @nononope It depends on how you think about it, actually it constructs a reference and returns. While you can also think that they're just reference binding.